# NullReferenceException on data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, listbox

I have a datagrid (DevExpress) in a WPF user control

dg_VQ is the datagrid name

I have a list box lst_REQ_LIST

In the SelectionChanged I reload 2 data grids

The line in _load_data
this.dg_VQ.ItemsSource = null;

is where the exception is occuring.
the way it occures is what has me boggled
If I select an item in the list it works no mater how many times I select something.
However, as soon as I select an iem that has data in the grid(s) and then I select another item in the list the error is raised.

Here is the goofy part, if I put a stop on the line it works. it is almost like it is waiting for something to finish in a different thread, yet there are no known spin off threads. the catch is never hit in the routine.

it just pops a message box with the exception

Using data classes

```
    private void lst_REQ_LIST_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lst_REQ_LIST.SelectedValue == null) { return; }
        _selection_changed();
    }
    private void _selection_changed()
    {
        string sGUID = lst_REQ_LIST.SelectedValue.ToString().ToUpper();
        req_guid = new Guid(sGUID);
        quote_guid = new Guid("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}");
        _load_data();
    }
    private void _load_data()
    {
        try
        {
            // Load the top grid
            this.dg_VQ.ItemsSource = null;
            this.dg_VQ.ItemsSource = dbP.tbl_vendor_quote_requests
                .Where(x => x.requisition_guid == req_guid);
            this.dg_VQ.RefreshData();

            // Load the bottom grid
            this.dg_VQ_DTL.ItemsSource = null;
            this.dg_VQ_DTL.ItemsSource = db.tbl_vendor_quote_request_dtls
                .Where(x => x.vendor_quote_request_guid == quote_guid)
                .OrderBy(x => x.item_number);
            this.dg_VQ_DTL.RefreshData();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you that `this.dg_VQ` is `null`. Make sure you've set that field to an actual value, **or** wrap your logic with

```
if (this.dg_VQ != null)
{
    ...
}
```

This won't solve the original issue but it will prevent a `NullReferenceException` in your code.